# Laravel : Model function to get total price based on relashioships from view

Tags: laravel, model, relationship

i have  :

***Sales table***

---

id | name

---

***Services table :***

---

id | sale_id | name | type | city

---

***Prices table :***

---

id | type | city | price

---

i want to get the total price of services of a sale directly from a view using function on a model.

exemple :

sale(1) -> has 2 services -> each service has a price on Prices table based on type and city -> Total price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is a little bit different

Model `Sale.php`

```php
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sale extends Model
{
    function services() {
        return $this->hasMany(Service::class);
    }
    function price() {
        return $this->services->sum('price.price');
    }
}
```

Model `Service.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Service extends Model
{
    function sale() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Sale::class);
    }
    function price() {
        return $this->hasOne(Price::class, 'type', 'type')
            ->where('prices.city', $this->city);
    }
}
```

And you just call the function price on your Sale model.

```php
\App\Sale::find(3)->price()
```

Or you can make it in an attribute

```php
function getPriceAttribute() {
    return $this->services->sum('price.price');
}
```

and just get that attribute like this

```php
\App\Sale::find(3)->price
```

But what I would do is move type and city to `Price` and only have price_id in the `Service`

Let me know if this helps you :D

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no relationship between price table, use `city` and `type` to search from `price` table.

Assume that you have a `$sale` object.

```php
// all the prices which is for particular types and cities got from $sale
$prices = Price::where(function($query) use ($sale) {
    $query->whereIn('type', $sale->services()->pluck('type')->toArray())
        ->whereIn('city', $sale->services()->pluck('city')->toArray());
});

$totalPrice = $prices->sum->price
```